# Rails gem BluePrinter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you get current `:view` parameter being passed to a BluePrint?

```
class ThisModelBlueprint < Blueprinter::Base
  identifier :id
  association :other_models, view: (self.view==:admin? (:extended) : (:normal))
```

and then in `this_models_controller.rb`

```
render json: ThisModelBlueprint.render(
  @this_models,
  view: @current_user.clearance_level
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a conditional in the controller where you set the view, and have it return extended or normal based on `clearance_level` or you could jsut define the views to be the clearance level options and assign attributes there accordingly. And then you can can just use the same view name in each.

**Option1**

```rb
#controller
scoped_view = @current_user.clearance_level.admin? ? :extended : :normal
render json: ThisModelBlueprint.render(@this_model, view: scoped_view)

#serializer
view :normal do
  association :relation, view: :normal
  ...
end
view :extended do
  association :relation, view: :extended
  ...
end
```

**Option2**

```rb
#controller
render json: ThisModelBlueprint.render(@this_model, view: @current_user.clearance_level.to_sym)

#serializer
view :user do
  # fields that everyone can see
  fields ...
  association :relation, view: :user
end

view :admin do
  # includes all the fields/associations of the user view
  include_view :user
  # fields that only an admin can view
  fields ...
  association :relation, view: :admin
end
```